# Linq2Sql: linking tables without relationships

Tags: linq-to-sql, report, fogbugz

I'm new to Linq2Sql and to learn it I'm trying to setup reports using Linq2Sql against the FogBugz tables. But, since the FogBugz tables don't have any true Foreign Key relationships, LinqToSql isn't finding the relationships and I can't figure out how to create them through the Designer. So, is there a way to do this manually? If I do it manually and then later decide to add another table, will everything I did be overwritten?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add relationships (aka Associations) in the SQL2LINQ designer by right clicking the white space in the designer, choose Add -> Association.

Choose your parent and child tables (classes), then link the properties on the tables accordingly using the grid that appears below the dropdowns for parent and child classes